# Как определить длину строки string (strlen)?

Tags: c++

```
string x;
cout << "For the Add Elements Press 'A':n";
{
    char v = getch();
    if (v == 'a') {

        cout << "Enter Elements: n";
        getline(cin, x);  // Как определить длину введенного элемента через strlrn?

        L.ElAdd(x);
    }
    List L;
    L.print();
}
```

Comment: @navi1893, прямо написали strlen(x) и получилоь ? Или все-таки strlen(x.c_str()) ?

Comment: нет, когда писал strlen(x) мне выдавал ошибку size_t и это внизу @userx помог мне с подсказкой )

Comment: Тем не менее strlen тоже работает, но через метод .c_str(). А Вы почитайте документацию на класс string.

Comment: @avp добавил ссылку в ответ

Answer (score 11):

`x.length()`

[Класс `string`](http://cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/) на сайте cplusplus.com.

Answer (score 5):

Методы size и length класса string возвращают длину строки:

```
using namespace std;
string str("Hello world");
basic_string <char>::size_type size, length;

size = str.size();
length = str.length();
```